# Problema con bucle for, no entra

Tags: java

Tengo un problema, no me entra al bucle `for`:

```
    for(int j = 0;j >= items;j++){ //No entra al for
                        if(plugin.getPropertiesKit().getString("Kits."+allNameKits[w]+".name").equals(kit)){
                            itemsKit[k] = plugin.getPropertiesKit().getString("Kits."+allNameKits[w]+".item"+r); //No recibe valores
                            w++; r++;

                        }
                        k++;
                    }
```

Y esta es la clase completa:

```
package com.gmail.bruno.primerpluginmc;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;


public class comandos implements CommandExecutor{

private Main plugin;
ItemStack miItem = null;

public comandos(Main instance){
    plugin = instance;
}

@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
    if(label.equalsIgnoreCase("tutorial")){
        Player p = (Player) sender;
        darKit(p,args[0],null);
        /* Asi se añaden los permisos

        if (sender.hasPermission(plugin.perm_owner)){

        }*/
    }else if(label.equalsIgnoreCase("sql")){
            PlayerListener pl = new PlayerListener(plugin);
            pl.guardarDatos("TheBruno", 5);
            sender.sendMessage("Ingresado");

    }else if(label.equalsIgnoreCase("kit")){
        int numberKits = plugin.getPropertiesKit().getInt("Kits.numberOfKits");
        String[] kits = new String[numberKits];

        String kitSelected;

        if(args.length > 0){
            if(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("diamante")){
            kits = guardarDatos(numberKits,kits);
            kitSelected = args[0];

            //Recorro el array que contiene los nombres de los kits para comprobar cual es igual a kitSelected que contiene el kit introducido por el jugador
            int q = 0;
            boolean d = true;
            int n = 1;
            for(int g=0; g < kits.length;g++){
                if(!kits[q].equalsIgnoreCase(kitSelected) || kits[q].equalsIgnoreCase(kitSelected)){
                        if(sender instanceof Player){
                            Player p = (Player) sender;
                            darKit(p,args[0],kits);
                        }else{
                            sender.sendMessage("[PrimerPlugin] Este comando solo lo puede ejecutar un jugador");
                            sender.sendMessage("[PrimerPlugin] Los kits disponibles son");
                            break;
                        }
                }else{
                    while(d){
                        for(int i=1; i <= numberKits; i++){
                            String a = "Kits.kit"+n+".name";
                            sender.sendMessage("[PrimerPlugin] "+plugin.getPropertiesKit().getString(a));
                            //Aqui acaba de imprimir los nombres de los kits
                            n++;
                        }
                        sender.sendMessage(args[0]);
                        d = false;
                    }
                }
                q++;
            }
            }
            //Aqui acaba el recorrido 

                }else if(args.length == 0){
                    int n = 1;
                    //Bucle for para imprimir en el chat el nombre de todos los kits de propertiesKits.yml
                    for(int i=1; i <= numberKits; i++){
                    String a = "Kits.kit"+n+".name";
                    sender.sendMessage("[PrimerPlugin] "+plugin.getPropertiesKit().getString(a));
                    //Aqui acab de imprimir los nombres de los kits
                    n++;
                }
                }
            }
    return true; //Si lo cambio a false, se imprimira el comnado introducido como si se tratase de un mensaje

    }
                                                                                        ////////////////
public void darKit(Player p, String kit, String[] kits){ //kit --> diamante
    List<String> listaKits = new ArrayList<String>();

    listaKits.addAll(plugin.getPropertiesKit().getConfigurationSection("Kits").getKeys(false));

    String[] allNameKits = new String[plugin.getPropertiesKit().getInt("Kits.numberOfKits")+1];
    int z = 0;
        for(String il : listaKits){
            allNameKits[z] = il;
            z++;
            if(z > 2) break;
        }
        darKit2(p, kit, allNameKits);
}

    public void darKit2(Player p, String kit, String[] allNameKits){
        int w = 0, r = 1;
        for(int g = 0; g <= plugin.getPropertiesKit().getInt("Kits.numberOfKits");g++){
            if(allNameKits[0].equals("numberOfKits")){     ///////////////////////
                w = 1;
                String kitName = plugin.getPropertiesKit().getString("Kits."+allNameKits[w]+".name");

                if(kitName.equals(kit)){
                    int items = plugin.getPropertiesKit().getInt("Kits."+allNameKits[w]+".numberOfItems"); // 5
                    String[] itemsKit = new String[items];
                    int k = 0, m = 1;
                    plugin.getLogger().info("HOLA");

                    for(int j = 0;j >= items;j++){ //No entra al for
                        if(plugin.getPropertiesKit().getString("Kits."+allNameKits[w]+".name").equals(kit)){
                            itemsKit[k] = plugin.getPropertiesKit().getString("Kits."+allNameKits[w]+".item"+r); //No recibe valores
                            w++; r++;

                        }
                        k++;
                    }

                    plugin.getLogger().info("Valor de itemsKit"+"["+k+"]"+itemsKit[k]);
                    int l = 0;
                    for(int h = 0;h <= items;h++){
                        miItem = new ItemStack(Material.getMaterial(itemsKit[0]));
                        l++;
                    }

                }
                }
            }
        miItem = new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND);//getMaterial(itemsKit[0]));
        miItem.setAmount(1);
        p.getInventory().addItem(miItem);
        p.sendMessage("[PrimerPlugin] Has recibido el kit "+ChatColor.AQUA+kit);
        }

public String[] guardarDatos(int numberKits, String[] kits){
    int k = 0;
    int m = 1;
    //Bucle for que almacena en el array kits el nombre de todos los kits de propertiesKits.yml
    for(int j=1; j <= numberKits; j++){
        String a = "Kits.kit"+m+".name";
        kits[k] = plugin.getPropertiesKit().getString(a);
        m++;
        k++;
    }
    return kits;
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como bien te apuntaban, el problema está en la condición, ahora tienes que ver que el array itemsKit[k] no tiene definida la posición más alta, desde mi punto de vista la condición debería de ser la siguiente:

```
for(int j = 0;j < items;j++){
```

Answer (score 3):

El problema está en la condición `>=`:

```
for(int j = 0;j >= items;j++){
                ^^ aquí
```

Debería ser `<=`:

```
for(int j = 0;j <= items;j++){
```

Comment: apuesto por una `IndexOutOfBoundsException` con esa condicion... :D

Comment: @JordiCastilla pues revisando el código de la pregunta, esa variable `j` no se utiliza como índice para un ciclo `for`, por ende no habrá la excepción que indicad :D

Comment: @MiquelColl favor de leer mi comentario anterior.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Tienes toda la razón! Disculpa.. (es un poco raro la verdad xD).

Comment: @MiquelColl si que hay IOOBE porque se usa para indicar el tamaño del array `String[] kits = new String[numberKits];` y despues se la mete al metodo para decirle al bucle cuantas iteraciones debe dar, asi que ahi sale la exception

Comment: @JordiCastilla pero no utilitza la variable j para ello..

Comment: @MiquelColl no, porque lo hace mal y tiene otros contadores innecesarios, pero estos contadores daran una vuelta de más  y petara  aqui `itemsKit[k]` ya que `k` tendra el mismo valor que `j`.... ergo... me reafirmo en mi primer comentario, mi downvote y en no estar de  acuerdo con que sea la respuesta aceptada.... pd: utili**t**za <3 jejjeje

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza creo que JordiCastilla tiene razón ya que 'j=k' en este caso... PD: se me escapan hahaha